# $wpdb get_results - loop from specific category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this code, its working good, but its gets posts from all categories. I need to get posts only from category ID 2. I tried to add "AND term_taxonomy_id = 2" to my code, but this didint work. Can somebody help me with this, my code:

```
<?php //loops all posts
                $my_query = $wpdb->get_results
                ("SELECT * FROM `{$table_prefix}posts`, {$table_prefix}postmeta 
                WHERE {$table_prefix}posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                AND {$table_prefix}posts.id = {$table_prefix}postmeta.post_id 
                AND {$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_key` = 'wpcf-data-nuo' ORDER BY if({$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_value` = '' or {$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_value` is null,1,0), {$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_value` ASC LIMIT 12");
                foreach($my_query as $post) {
                    setup_postdata($post);
            ?>
```

Comment: Why do u write custom query ?

Comment: For custom metakey order by date

Comment: you can do it by WP_QUERY for custom meta parameters and ORDER. look for WP_QUERY on WordPress docs

Comment: Maybe but i not really understand how to do it with my meta_key ordering

Comment: `<?php 
   // the query
   
   $the_query = new WP_Query(array(

   'post_type'       => 'post',      
   'posts_per_page'  => 8,
   'cat' => 2,
   'meta_key'  => 'wpcf-data-nuo',
   'orderby'  => 'meta_value'

   ));
    ?>`

Comment: Something like this, but its not correctly ordering my post by meta_key like its ordering with my first code

Comment: Try like this `$the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'cat' => 2, 'meta_key' => 'wpcf-data-nuo', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC'));`

Comment: For understanding the meta_key wpcf-data-nuo is a date input, and i need to order posts by closest dates. So if the meta_key date is 2018-01-25 - the post should be first in a row

Comment: are you able to get the records without order?

Comment: Yes its showings posts and without order

Comment: see my answer below, it will help you regarding sort order

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code, Hope! its working

You can define the meta key for orderby parameter using the old method (I tested on WP 3.1.1)...

```html
query_posts(
    array(  'post_type' => 'services',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'meta_key' => 'some_key',
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value', //or 'meta_value_num'
            'meta_query' => array(
                                array('key' => 'order_in_archive',
                                      'value' => 'some_value'
                                )
                            )
    )
);
```

**OR**

For me, I wanted to order by a numeric field and I had to use 'type' => 'NUMERIC' inside the meta query.

This issue in general is cleared up in WordPress 4.2 by using named queries. e.g.

```html
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'services',
  'orderby'   => 'order_clause',
  'meta_query' => array(
       'order_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'order_in_archive',
            'value' => 'some_value',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC' // unless the field is not a number
)));
```

Reference link for set the meta value in query: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html

Comment: But this code dont have my custom meta_key ordering by date

Comment: ok... you want to get the code as your custom meta_key ordering by date??

Comment: Look at my code its not only getting the posts but its has and "if"

Comment: AND {$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_key` = 'wpcf-data-nuo' ORDER BY if({$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_value` = '' or {$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_value` is null,1,0), {$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_value` ASC LIMIT 12");

Comment: `<?php 
   // the query
   
   $the_query = new WP_Query(array(

   'post_type'       => 'post',      
   'posts_per_page'  => 8,
   'cat' => 2,
   'meta_key'  => 'wpcf-data-nuo',
   'orderby'  => 'meta_value'

   ));
    ?>`

Comment: Something like this but i dont know how to implement the meta_key ordering in it

Comment: What does 'value' => 'some_value' - it is neded for me? Whit your code i get the posts by meta_value but its need to be reverse, because my meta_value is a date field and i need to loop posts by closest dates.

Comment: You can check it live on www.ft.lt where is Kelionės po Lietuvą section

Comment: follow this url for your guidance https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html

Comment: This tutorial show loop in a range of meta value its not what i need. Maybe can you just add a code to my first wpdb-> get_results code that it get posts only from category id 2? I think its will be easyer

Comment: you have to understand the tutorial and set the query value as per require details. so, you can get the data.

Comment: im beginner so i dont understand and why can you use my code to add category?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by WP_QUERY instead writing custom Query.

> The query to get the results and then your custom **sort order** by **altering the WP_QUERY** if default order parameters not work as expected.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'cat' => 2,
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-data-nuo',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'filter_query');
$q = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'filter_query');

function filter_query( $orderby_statement ) {
    global $table_prefix;
    $orderby_statement .= " if({$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_value` = '' ";
    $orderby_statement .= " or {$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_value` is null,1,0), {$table_prefix}postmeta.`meta_value`";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

**Note:** Do not remove spaces from `$orderby_statement .=` because it require spaces while running query.

If it still doesn't work, then add `var_dump($orderby_statement);` before `return $orderby_statement;` then copy the SQL and add it in your question so it will help us to understand what is the issue.

Comment: Why just you cant add additional code to my SQL code to filter from category? Why its need this WP_QUERY hard code?

Comment: Because it is the proper way coding in wordpress, see [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) AND WHY read [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-wp_query-an-introduction--cms-23023)

Comment: Can you post not proper way for me please i searching for this all day

Comment: string(193) "secretprefix_d23da_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC if(secretprefix_d23da_postmeta.`meta_value` = '' or secretprefix_d23da_postmeta.`meta_value` is null,1,0), secretprefix_d23da_postmeta.`meta_value`"

Comment: can you please post what `var_dump($q->request);` says ?

Comment: It says: string(193) "secretprefix_d23da_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC if(secretprefix_d23da_postmeta.meta_value = '' or secretprefix_d23da_postmeta.meta_value is null,1,0), secretprefix_d23da_postmeta.meta_value

Comment: i am asking about this query `$q = new WP_Query($args); var_dump($q->request); `